# How to ensure disjoint set of features when using Feature Union

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to learn how to use some of the helper features in sklearn but am struggling with understanding how to use FeatureUnion

One part of the documentation states this

> (A FeatureUnion has no way of checking whether two transformers might
>   produce identical features. It only produces a union when the feature
>   sets are disjoint, and making sure they are is the caller’s
>   responsibility.)

However an example on the Iris dataset shows this

```
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# This dataset is way to high-dimensional. Better do PCA:
pca = PCA(n_components=2)

# Maybe some original features where good, too?
selection = SelectKBest(k=1)

# Build estimator from PCA and Univariate selection:

combined_features = FeatureUnion([("pca", pca), ("univ_select", selection)])

# Use combined features to transform dataset:
X_features = combined_features.fit(X, y).transform(X)
```

How is it ensured that the pca and SelectKBest functions don't select the same feature, or in other words how can the user ensure that the two selections are disjoint?

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/pipeline.html#feature-union

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_stacker.html#example-feature-stacker-py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you pretty much answered your own question with that quote from the docs:

> (A FeatureUnion has no way of checking whether two transformers might produce identical features. It only produces a union when the feature sets are disjoint, and making sure they are is the caller’s responsibility.)

The `FeatureUnion` **does not ensure features are different**.

In the example of the Iris dataset it is possible (though highly unlikely) that the PCA and the feature selection process will generate identical features. In that case, you just have twice the same feature in the output of the `FeatureUnion`.

This is usually *not a huge deal*, though if you can avoid it it's probably cleaner to do so (for instance a random forest model would be biased towards a feature that is present several times, as it would have a higher probability to be picked as a candidate to split a node).

To be a bit clearer, I don't think there's a lot you can do about it beyond avoiding to combine feature extraction processes that obviously create duplicate features in a FeatureUnion.